# Should I include this scholarship on my application?

Tags: phd, united-states, application, awards, spain

On my senior year in high school, I, along with 5 other people, won a scholarship based on academic excellence, granted by my city's Department of Education. Now I am applying to a PhD and I don't know if I should include this in the Awards section of the application, as I don't know if this is relevant enough (for context: the city's population is around 25000 people, it's not a big city).

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you not include that? Worst case scenario, the committee will ignore it. Unless there is some other reason not to include it, such as page limits that force you to make choices with other awards.

Comment: One possible reason not to include it is if this was the only scholarship and award received. Having a full section with only one entry might draw attention to the lack of other results (which is not bad of itself, but you also wouldn't want to draw too much attention). Then again, you could still include it in your CV as a bullet point under your high-school point, rather under its own section.

Comment: I agree with @Andrea, which probably should be expanded into an answer. Also, the demographics of the city should be considered. For example, in 2020 in the U.S. the population was about 330 million and about 3.6 million of these graduated high school (that year), which is about 1% of the population. Thus, 5 graduating people out of a population of 25,000 represents (using the 1% value) 5 people out of 250, or 1 out of 50. Also in the U.S. about 2% have a Ph.D., which is also 1 out of 50. In light of figures such as these, the award might not be very meaningful at this point in the OPs life.

Answer (score 2):

You can include it or not, but it won't have much of any effect in the US. There is an informal weighting system that values recent things over earlier. It certainly wouldn't overcome a generally poor application.

On the other hand, no one will object to it and it is fine to include things you are proud of. I probably did something similar myself. If you have an Awards section already, then it would be pretty natural to include it, as long as it is clear that it is from secondary school.